# htaccess 2 conditions, Redirecting to and from a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

Redirect all calls from **site.com/api/*** to **index.php**

Redirect all calls from **site.com/*** (not /api) to **public/** folder

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

My code is not working